# Transforming data frame using column names r

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
beta1   beta2    beta3
 4       67       89
 33       7       78
 6       99       33
etc
```

Now I want to transform this data frame to a different dataframe which looks like

```
col1  col2
4     beta1
33    beta1
6     beta1
67    beta2 
etc
```

So, the columns have to be pasted below eachother and the second column should consist of the colnames of the first data frame. Does anyone know how to do this without loop?

Comment: Check for `melt`, `gather`, and similar functions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 do.call(rbind,
        lapply(names(df1), function(nm){
            data.frame(col1 = df1[[nm]],
                       col2 = nm)
        }))
#  col1  col2
#1    4 beta1
#2   33 beta1
#3    6 beta1
#4   67 beta2
#5    7 beta2
#6   99 beta2
#7   89 beta3
#8   78 beta3
#9   33 beta3
```

## DATA

```
df1 = structure(list(beta1 = c(4L, 33L, 6L),
                     beta2 = c(67L, 7L, 99L),
                     beta3 = c(89L, 78L, 33L)),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Or `stack(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a reshaping (from wide to long) operation. You can use `dplyr::gather()` function:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(beta1 = c(4,33,6),beta2 = c(67,7,99), beta3= c(89,78,33))

dat %>% gather(Col1, Col2)
```

Comment: FYI: `gather` is in the "tidyr" package and not "dplyr" package

Answer (score 1):

and the usual data.table approach:

```
library( data.table )
data <- fread("beta1   beta2    beta3
4       67       89
33       7       78
6       99       33")



melt( data, 
      measure.vars = patterns( "^beta" ), 
      variable.name = "col2", 
      value.name = "col1" )

#     col2 col1
# 1: beta1    4
# 2: beta1   33
# 3: beta1    6
# 4: beta2   67
# 5: beta2    7
# 6: beta2   99
# 7: beta3   89
# 8: beta3   78
# 9: beta3   33
```